# Image scale in TextView

Tags: android

I use `TextView` and drawableRight:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/text1_2"
   android:drawableRight="@drawable/star"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
   android:textSize="@dimen/category_bottom_text_size" />
```

But the image does not scale according to the `textView`'s height and just crops. I tried different solutions, such as using a bitmap file for this image and making the image `.9`, but the result was the same.

Comment: can you use imageview itself?

Comment: layout_height should be wrap_content

Comment: android:drawableRight can not be scaled, so you have to use big image instead or you can use seperate image from textview by using imageview seperately

Answer (score 0):

Try to used.. textview in image scale

```
        android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
```

Comment: it will also scale the text